# Excel IF formula between two times in day

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to have a formula that will tell me if the time in a cell is between a range of time by returning a Yes or No value.

I used a code for one time, but am having a hard time expanding the formula for two times.

```
=IF(G2="","",IF(G2<(--"12:00 PM"),"Yes","No"))
```

The above code works

```
=IF(H2="","",IF(H2<(--"12:00 PM"),H2<(--"3:00PM")),"Yes","No"))
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Just to be sure you want to EXCLUDE all times between Noon and 3pm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use AND():

```
=IF(H2="","",IF(AND(H2<(--"12:00 PM"),H2>(--"3:00 PM")),"Yes","No"))
```

Comment: Hi, thank you! I just typed in "=IF(G2="","",IF(AND(G2>(--"12:00 PM"),G2<(--"3:00PM")),"Yes","No"))" and got a #VALUE! response. I'm wondering what may be causing this?

Comment: You are getting error because there is no space in between `3:00PM` it should be `3:00 PM`

Comment: @LP so essentially it should be `=IF(G2="","",IF(AND(G2>(--"12:00 PM"),G2<(--"3:00 PM")),"Yes","No"))`

Answer (score 1):

You may try this way as well,

```
=IF(H2="","",IF(AND(H2<0.5,H2>0.625),"Yes","No"))

Where 0.5=12:00 PM
Where 0.625=3:00 PM
```